# Fontstyle not correct in a foreach loop with If statements

Tags: c#, fonts, foreach

I am probably missing something realy simple, but i cannot get it to work properly.

I am filling a Datagridview. Then i have a Databindingcomplete event to go over the rows and give them colors and fonts depending on certain criteria.

This is done with the following code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if ((r.Cells["referrer"].Value.ToString().Contains("DBS")) & (r.Cells["priority"].Value.ToString().Equals("1")))
                {
                    r.DefaultCellStyle = DBS;
                    r.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
                }

                else if ((r.Cells["referrer"].Value.ToString().Contains("DBS")) & (r.Cells["priority"].Value.ToString().Equals("0")))
                {
                    r.DefaultCellStyle = DBS;
                    r.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular);
                }

                else if ((r.Cells["referrer"].Value.ToString().Contains("agenda")) & (r.Cells["priority"].Value.ToString().Equals("0")))
                {
                    r.DefaultCellStyle = agenda;
                    r.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular);
                }

                else if ((r.Cells["referrer"].Value.ToString().Contains("agenda")) & (r.Cells["priority"].Value.ToString().Equals("1")))
                {
                    r.DefaultCellStyle = agenda;
                    r.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
                }

                else if ((r.Cells["referrer"].Value.ToString().Contains("sms")) & (r.Cells["priority"].Value.ToString().Equals("1")))
                {
                    r.DefaultCellStyle = sms;
                    r.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
                }

                else if ((r.Cells["referrer"].Value.ToString().Contains("sms")) & (r.Cells["priority"].Value.ToString().Equals("0")))
                {
                   r.DefaultCellStyle = sms;
                   r.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular);
                }

                else if ((r.Cells["referrer"].Value.ToString().Contains("remoteLogin")) & (r.Cells["priority"].Value.ToString().Equals("1")))
                {
                    r.DefaultCellStyle = remoteLogin;
                    r.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
                }

                else if ((r.Cells["referrer"].Value.ToString().Contains("remoteLogin")) & (r.Cells["priority"].Value.ToString().Equals("0")))
                {
                    r.DefaultCellStyle = remoteLogin;
                    r.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular);
                }
            }
```

Now this is working. the first line of the DefaultCellStyle is for colors of the row, then the second line is the font.

Everything works ok, colors are good, bold works, regular works, except one thing.

If i have 2 rows:

A) agenda with priority 1

B) agenda with priority 0

It will go past the first one, adjusts the color good, makes it bold. But then the second one will also be bold. If i change them so the first one is priority 0, both will be regular.

I can have all types of events, all will be bold or regular, all have the correct color settings.  But when i have a second of of the same type (DBS, agenda, remoteLogin or sms) the second and so on will have the same font as the first one.

So this batch will do the following:

[DBS -  1] -->  Correct color, and bold (correct)

[agenda - 0] --> Correct color and regular (correct)

[sms - 1] -->  Correct color, and bold (correct)

[remoteLogin - 0] --> Correct color and regular (correct)

[DBS - 0] --> Correct color and Bold (Incorrect font!)

[agenda - 1] --> Correct color and regular (Incorrect font!)

I hope i make sense explaining. Maybe i'm not seeing something or i want something stupid. Maybe someone can tell me what is wrong. 
the code might not be the best now, since i have made many adjustments trying to make it work.

Edit:
I just noticed that it does do the foreach correct, but when it encounters the a second one of the same type, it will change the font of the one before also. Maybe i can work around it.

Thx in advance!
Mike

Comment: Are you in a position to debug this and go through step by step ensuring that your row values are definitely what you think they are and to see what the path through this code is? Given the code I can't see how this problem would happen...

Comment: Throw some tracing code into the loop. In each `if` do a `Response.Write` or `Console.WriteLine` with what you think should be there. Also, throw an `else` catch-all in there that does something wild like blue 30pt.

Comment: Wow, two Chris's, same ideas.

Comment: i just added a message box into the if statements, and i can see it goes into the correct one with every row it passes. I am beginning to think that the problem is inside the Fontstyle code. i need to reset it or something. Just don't know how or were to do that.

Comment: @ChrisHaas: Ah, but I didn't have the awesome 30pt blue idea. ;-)

Comment: All suggestions are welcome! If it's not the correct one i still get some insight into the problem and troubleshooting. I'm simply glad someone didn't come with "well doh! -insert very easy sollution i should of known myself" hehe

Comment: @MikevanHeugten: What are the values of `r.DefaultCellStyle` looking like as you go throught eh appropriate clauses? Are they looking like what you'd expect to start and end with?

Comment: I figured it out.

I create the DefaultCellStyle with the colors for each item (DBS, agenda, etc.)
Then i change the Font of that DefaultCellStyle to Bold or regular.

When the foreach loop encounters a second row of the same type. It loads the same DefaultCellStyle, lets say "DBS" as the other one. Inside of that i adjust the Fontstyle. 

Because i now update the Fontstyle inside the "DBS" item, all rows with the "DBS" DefaultCellStyle get affected.

I think the only way around this is to make a diffrent DefaultCellStyle for each option in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I create the DefaultCellStyle with the colors for each item (DBS, agenda, etc.) Then i change the Font of that DefaultCellStyle to Bold or regular. When the foreach loop encounters a second row of the same type. It loads the same DefaultCellStyle, lets say "DBS" as the other one. Inside of that i adjust the Fontstyle. Because i now update the Fontstyle inside the "DBS" item, all rows with the "DBS" DefaultCellStyle get affected. I think the only way around this is to make a diffrent DefaultCellStyle for each option in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your `&`'s should be `&&`, I suspect.

Comment: Surely the only difference that makes is short circuiting? There are no side effects in the check so it doesn't matter if you run it unnecessarily and this shouldn't change the result should it? Can you expand on why you think this is the problem?

Comment: Tried both & and &&, used .Equals and .Contains, used If and Else If, result stays the same. first one is ok, then the font won't change correctly.

Comment: It is best practice to use &&, although in C# both are logically equivalent, the difference is that && allows short circuiting to take place (stops evaluating when the statement result is already known), whereas the & evaluates conditions on both sides, even if the first one has already evaluated to false.

Comment: I know, and i did start out with that, but since i was stuck i started changing stuff to make it work. When i find the problem i will clean up my code again, and use &&.